# Ruby regex for chemical formula subscript/superscript

Tags: html, ruby, regex

I want to substitute sub and sup tags into a chemical formula, for example C7[2H]5NaO2, and get as as result:

```
C<sub>7</sub>[<sup>2</sup>H]<sub>5</sub>NaO<sub>2</sub>
```

The numbers inside the tags can be two digit numbers. I know so far that /(\d+) / will match all digits, and /[(\d+)/ matches the digit after the [, but I don't know how to combine these two.

Comment: Do you have any other samples, I fear any solutions given on this single sample will fail once you attempt to apply it to other formulae

Comment: This is a more complicated problem than you probably think, if you want it to be general. Chemical formulae pretty much have their own grammar. You would probably have to resort to a grammar parser like Parslet or TreeTop.

Comment: Is this Ruby as in the programming language or Ruby as in [`<ruby>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby)?

Comment: Which is the input and which is the output?

Comment: Why is the question downvoted? I presented a specific scenario of this formula, that's the format that the data will come in. I don't care for other variations of the formula, I didn't say in the question that the there will be variations of this formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in two separate steps.

First, replace digits preceded by letters with the same digit surrounded by `sup` tags.

Match: `(?<=[A-Z])\d+`

Replace: `<sup>\0</sup>`

Then take the result and replace digits preceded by `[` with the same digit surrounded by `sub` tags:

Match: `(?<=\[)\d+`

Replace: `<sub>\0</sub>`

Comment: Thank you, after modifying your answer to: `'C7[2H]5NaO2'.gsub(/(?<=[A-Z|\]])\d+/, '<sub>\0</sub>').gsub(/(?<=\[)\d+/, '<sup>\0</sup>')` it worked